# Not able to access the server after changing the password?

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, windows-xp, network-share

While accessing the server, the error comes:

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

I am logging in from Administrator in XP machine, able to access server from other machines. Is there any problem with administrator profile??

Comment: If one of the answers below solved your problem, you should mark the answer as accepted.  It will help other visitors to the site to see what the solution was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This caused because you opened the UNC with a userid that had access to the UNC, but no longer can access the share. This info is stored in the profile.

> Goto Start -> Run

Type

> cmd /k net use

Click k

You will see a list of existing connections to all the file shares. 
If you see the server listed, then you need to disconnect and reconnect the share

Goto My Computer -> Tools -> Disconnect Network drive. Pick the one to disconnect

Then remap the drive

Comment: thanx........guys !!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're trying to access the server via UNC path, if so then check in Control Panel>Stored Usernames and Passwords for any cached credentials for the server and delete them if they exist. Also run Net Use from a command prompt and check for any mappings to the server and delete them if they exist. Then try again to access the server.